# Angular ui router ui-sref-active on parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have one *parent* state and many childs states. If I want the `ui-sref-active` on the parent to work when I am on one of the child I need to do this "hack":

```
$scope.isActive = function() {  
   return $state.includes('playLotteries.Index') 
       || $state.includes('playLotteries.Group')  
       || $state.includes('playLotteries.hunter');
   }
```

This is very ugly way and I have many children so its not seems like good solution. Anyone have another solution for this problem?

Comment: You should just be able to use ui-sref-active, according to the docs "Will activate when the ui-sref's target state or any child state is active".  Note that it says "or any child state" http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

Comment: Did you check only parent state "return $state.includes('playLotteries')" ?

Comment: Thats not working, only the default child route is making the parent to be active too, when i move to other childs its active class is gone

Comment: @Asik thats working you can write this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check `parent state` only instead of checking `all child` states

```
$scope.isActive = function() {  
   return $state.includes('playLotteries');
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far when working with a parent abstract state. If the parent is not an abstract state, is better to go with *ui-sref-active*.

Comment: please see answer below using wildcard to match

Answer (score 12):

There is a `UI-Router` directive:

> **`ui-sref-active="class-name-to-use"`**

which from a version [0.2.11](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/0.2.11) does exactly what we need:

> #### **uiSrefActive:**
>
> **BREAKING CHANGE:** Also activate for child states. (bf163ad, closes #818)
>   **uiSrefActiveEq:** new directive with old ui-sref-active behavior

so, if we want just assign class for exact match, we have to use this: **`ui-sref-active-eq="class-name-to-use"`**

So, why are you experiencing: this is not working?

> Because **it is working only in conjunction with `ui-sref` directive.**

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XxPYgNquo1X9YwizYVSX?p=preview)

These won't work as expected:

```
// NOT working as expected
<a ui-sref-active="current" href="#/home">
<a ui-sref-active="current" href="#/home/child1">
<a ui-sref-active="current" href="#/home/child2">
```

But these **will be working**:

```
// conjunction ui-sref and ui-sref-active is working
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home">
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child1">
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child2">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XxPYgNquo1X9YwizYVSX?p=preview). Example uses this [UI-Router 0.2.12 release](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/0.2.12) - and this [zip](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/archive/0.2.12.zip)

#### EXTEND: Parent should be abstract, some of its children should always be selected

In that case, we can use another feature of the `UI-Router`, the: [$urlRouterProvider.when()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider).

There is [extended plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OO3msU8sFbk90FFU2YX?p=preview) So, with state definition like this:

```
// when 'home' is selected ... 'home.child2' is used for redirection 
$urlRouterProvider.when('/home', '/home/child2');
// instead of 'other' - its 'other.child2' is used... could be any (e.g. other.child1)
$urlRouterProvider.when('/other', '/other/child2');

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/child2');
```

So, now, always child is selected (even if navigating to parent) and parent is getting its `ui-sref-active`. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OO3msU8sFbk90FFU2YX?p=preview)

Comment: But now if i want to redirect users directly to home.child1 instead to go to parent because there isnt a view in the parent,  this isnt working.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you show me that? Could you update my plunker and show what is not working? If I will know, I can assist to solve your issue...

Comment: lets say i have a parent thats called account and inside i have tabs children like personal info, purchases... so when user click on my account in the top nav bar the link is:
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="account.personalInfo">
so he goes directly to this child view.

Comment: Honestly, not sure if I understand 100%. But I created new plunker and extended my answer. So, now, while we do have parent - one of its children is always selected. The **`ui-sref-active`** is working as expected... Does this help?

Comment: Yes this is one more solution to the problem, But i dont know if i prefer this about the answer above. Because if i change the url so i need to be careful and change in the when method too and i noticed its cause some delay until the redirection happens, But thanks a lot, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Radim Köhler hello, but with `<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home">
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child1">
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child2">` in your example is allways home state will active. how we can select `home` only when clicking on it?

Answer (score 1):

Extending Radim Köhler's post. In case you are using an [index state with an abstract parent state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state), such as

```
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.index">Home</a>
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child1">Home » Child1</a>
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child2">Home » Child2</a>
```

… and want "Home" to be displayed as active when being on `home.child1`, you could make use of a CSS-hidden first `ui-sref`:

```
<li ui-sref-active="current">
  <a style="display:none" ui-sref="home"></a>
  <a ui-sref="home.index">Home</a>
</li>
<li ui-sref-active="current">
  <a ui-sref="home.child1">Home » Child1</a>
</li>
<li ui-sref-active="current">
  <a ui-sref="home.child2">Home » Child2</a>
</li>
```

This works since "`ui-sref-active` can live on the same element as `ui-sref` or on a parent element. The first `ui-sref-active` found at the same level or above the `ui-sref` will be used." per [ui-sref-active reference](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active)

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vKAYQNL8vj7TYpPzq6VZ?p=preview) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

`ui-sref-active` can take an object using a `*[wild card]` to match child states. This will work with abstract states.

```
<li ui-sref-active="{'active':'playLotteries.**'">
    <span>section</span>
    <ul>
        <li ui-sref-active="playLotteries.Index">
            <a ui-sref="playLotteries.Index">Index</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="playLotteries.Group">
            <a ui-sref="playLotteries.Group">Group</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="playLotteries.hunter">
            <a ui-sref="playLotteries.hunter">hunter</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Learn more about the [uiSrefActive directive](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/directives.html#uisrefactive)