# Angular routes & active links

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make selected link on navigation bar highlighted based on current location in the url. For that I have written following function in controller for navbar:

```
$scope.isActive = function(route) {
  return route === $location.path();
};
```

and in html I have this:

```
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/admin')}"><a href="/admin">Admin</a></li>
```

This works well for simple url but does not perform well for urls with id and subpaths. I mean if I have url as 'item/:id' it does not match in isActive function and does not get highlighted, also I want to highlight same `li` for multiple sub routes like `item` menu should be highlighted for `items` & `items/:id` & `items/my`. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26977126/1679310) where are explained all the details how **active** link could be solved with UI-Router...

Comment: @RadimKöhler let me check and try it out.

Comment: @RadimKöhler you are demonstrating `<a>` tag but I want to change class for `<li>` tag and when tried its not working.

Comment: Just wanted to give you a hint, how the "standard" UI-Router soltuion was designed... ;) Because as far as I remeber (from my plays...) it could be applied on LI as well, just ui-sref must be in place...

Comment: @RadimKöhler ok, I updated some bits here and there and now its working somewhat. Only problem is I can not directly go to abstract state. I mean I have given abstract state id into ui-sref so its getting highlighted everytime a child state is selected but when I click on that link it gives error like `Cannot transition to abstract state 'item'`

Comment: Yes yes... but that is not an issue! Why? just remove the abstract... and try to create some handling arround... to select one substate as default. Check it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/23658846/1679310 and in case you are using 0.2.13 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/27120308/1679310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<li ng-class="{isActive('/admin')? 'active' : ''}"><a href="/admin">Admin</a></li>
```

or

```
$scope.getActiveClass = function(route) {
  return (route === $location.path())? 'active' : '';
};


//in directive
<li ng-class="getActiveClass ('/admin')"><a href="/admin">Admin</a></li>
```

Comment: For simple routes its already working. I want to make it work for complex and sub routes.

Comment: You can use regexp for sub routes