# Navigate from parent state to children state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have the below states, they appear in a menu which has a submenu.

What I would like to do is, when I click on the first state (`'app.web'`), to have in the menu **both** buttons **'active'** *(I use `ui-sref-active="active"` on main and sub menu `<li>`)* and when I click on the second state, to have again both buttons 'active'.

At the moment, the below setup is

- not working if I click the main menu, but
- is working when I click the sub menu button.

main menu link state:

```
.state('app.web', {
  url: '/:webID/dashboard',
  views: {
    'container@': {
    templateUrl: '...',
  }
}
```

sub menu link state:

```
.state('app.web.dashboard', {
  url: '^/:webID/dashboard',
  views: {
    'container@': {
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: '...',
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to have both links to be marked with `"active"` ... *parent* and *child* ... even if **only parent** is selected. But this is **not** possible...

As we can read here:

#### [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active)

> **Description**
>
> A directive working alongside ui-sref to add classes to an element when the related ui-sref directive's state is active, and removing them when it is inactive. The primary use-case is to simplify the special appearance of navigation menus relying on ui-sref, by having the "active" state's menu button appear different, distinguishing it from the inactive menu items.
>
> ...
>
> Will activate when the ui-sref's target state **or any child state** is active...

As shown in the doc *(cited above)*: "*Will activate when the ui-sref's target state **or any child state** is active*".

Other words, having selected Parent - will never trigger that feature.

Here is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iyOnO3ywbqCqbgICqpaz?p=preview) showing how these links will be decorated:

```
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="app">
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="app.web({webID:123})">
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="app.web.dashboard({webID:123})">
```

EXTEND: why is [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OO3msU8sFbk90FFU2YX?p=preview) not working?

```
// working
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home">
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child1">
<a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref="home.child2">

// NOT WORKING
<a ui-sref-active="current" href="#/home">
<a ui-sref-active="current" href="#/home/child1">
<a ui-sref-active="current" href="#/home/child2">
```

The point is - **`ui-sref-active`** is dependent on `ui-sref`. The [above doc link says](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active):

> `ui-sref-active` can live on the same element as `ui-sref` or on a parent element. The first `ui-sref-active` found at the same level or above the `ui-sref` will be used.

The point is - we need **`ui-sref`**. Without that directive, the ui-sref-active simply won't work.

Some more details could be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977126/1679310)

Comment: Sorry for not explain it properly, I want to do something similar with http://plnkr.co/edit/7OO3msU8sFbk90FFU2YX?p=preview , look at home and home.child2

Comment: I extend my asnwer, hope it helps a bit. The point is **href** will not work, we need to have **ui-sref** in play. For more details please, also se: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26977126/1679310