# Angular ui-router ui-sref-active and Nested States

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 1.4.7, ui-router 0.2.15 and I want nested routes / nav bars to work. Currently I am using ui-sref-active to highlight the respective anchor in each navigation bar.

Here is a visual of the rendered HTML: http://s29.postimg.org/6hygp05mf/routing_example.png. I expect it to highlight a cell in each nav bar (i.e. Brainfood, Index). The top case passes, the bottom case fails.

**/brainfood**

- Expectation: It should highlight navigation items: "Brainfood", "Index".
- Passes

**/brainfood/items**

- Expectation: It should highlight navigation items: "Brainfood", "Items".
- FAIL: Brainfood not highlighted

**States**

Here are the states that I create (©=concrete, @=abstract).

```
ADD+ ©index /
ADD+ @brainfood /brainfood
ADD+ ©brainfood.index /
ADD+ ©brainfood.items /items
ADD+ ©brainfood.tags /tags
ADD+ @songfu /songfu
ADD+ ©songfu.index /
```

**Code - template**

```
<div>
    <div class="comp-navbar" ng-class="type">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="link in links" ui-sref-active="selected">
                <a ui-sref="{{ link.state }}">{{ link.name }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example? Having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish exactly

Comment: show some code so we can understand

Comment: You should probably use `ui-sref-active` instead of `ui-sref-active-eq`

Answer (score 0):

The top nav works as expected when I changed its ui-sref values from "brainfood.index" to "brainfood". Now when I go to "/brainfood/tags" it works as intended. However this breaks when I click on the top nav since I can't navigate to an abstract state.

There are two solutions:

1. [change your abstract states to concrete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977126/252462) (not desired)
2. [add an abstract redirect hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960288/angular-js-ui-router-how-to-redirect-to-a-child-state-from-a-parent)

Why is creating a basic nested view hierarchy with nested nav bars so difficult with ui-router? The main cause of this problem is a lack of separation between state identified and state desired (ui-sref).

A possible solution:

```
//Current directives:
ui-sref="state to navigate to"
ui-sref-active="class to toggle when state is active"

//New directive:
ui-sref-identity="define the state to use by ui-sref-active"
```